# Manually attaching SCC to an entire function?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Is it possible to manually attach an SCC to an entire function? For example, how do I attach an SCC to `f` in the following?

```
f x = g x
  where g x = ...
```

If I write

```
f x = {-# SCC f #-} g x y
  where g = ...
        y = ...
```

Then `g` and `y` won't be included in the SCC. Instead, it seems like I have to write

```
f x = {-# SCC f #-}
      let g = ...
          y = ...
      in  g x y
```

But this can be annoying because it requires rewriting `where` into `let` and guards into `case` statements. How can I get the same effect without doing all of this rewriting? -fprof-auto seems to be able to do this. But I only want to manually add SCC to a small number of functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this will be possible in the next major release of GHC (8.2), see this ticket [#12116](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/12116) (which shows the same workarounds and problems as you are having).

According to the [users guide](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/master/users-guide/profiling.html#inserting-cost-centres-by-hand) for the master branch of GHC you will be able to put the annotation at the same level as the declaration of `f`. Like

```
f x = g x y
  where g = ...
        y = ...
{-# SCC f #-}
```

or

```
f x = g x y
  where g = ...
        y = ...
{-# SCC f "some_cc_name" #-}
```